# Jenkins Pipeline: how to trigger a build as a downstream that requires an input

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins pipeline job defined. The `Jenkinsfile` of this job has an input defined using a dropdown. So when the build is triggered the user is requested to select an input.

For manually triggering this is working great!
However, if we want the same job to be triggered by another job as a downstream. How can we do this? providing the input parameters.

Thanks

Comment: Is the downstream job really using the `input` step or is it a parameterized build? If you can change it to a parameterized build (I wrote a [blog post](https://st-g.de/2016/12/parametrized-jenkins-pipelines) about that), then you can supply these parameters using the `build` step.

Comment: @stephenKing This is exactly the problem we are facing. Thanks for the fantastic blog. I shall use the approach you have detailed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @StephenKing pointed out to get setup we need, we have to move away from using `input` step and make the build parameterized.

The answer I was looking for is [here](https://st-g.de/2016/12/parametrized-jenkins-pipelines)